# Preserve new lines in postgres prepared statement via perl script

Tags: perl, postgresql

I need to insert data containing new lines into a text column. In doing a regular insert, the way I do that is with `... VALUES(E'Here comes a \\n new line)` which produces the following when queried:

```
Here Comes a
new line
```

However, when using a prepared statement such as:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO foo_table (foo_id, foo_bar_id, foo_text) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
my @data = (1, 9999, "E'Here comes a \\n new line'");
$sth->execute(@data);
```

the data that gets inserted is literally `E'Here comes a \n new line'` I have tried littering my value to insert with various `\` to see if escaping the characters was the issue, but if it is, I haven't found the right combination yet. Thanks for any help you can offer.

EDIT2: turns out I just needed a single `\` when using a prepared statement. Apparently, I overlooked the simplest solution when trying out all of the more complex escape sequences.

EDIT: The escaping mentioned in the answers below does not produce the desired result. It produces `Here comes a \n new line` when queried not

```
Here comes a
new line
```

like it does when using the `E'...'` syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just need to pass the value in. Let the driver deal with the escaping.

Answer (score 0):

The `E'Here comes a \\n new line'` is only used when it's embedded in a SQL statement.  In your case, just pass in

```
my @data = (1, 9999, "Here comes a \\n new line");
```

and the parameter binding mechanism will take of the escaping for you.